# Move an element in a list

Tags: python, list

If a list has elements like

```
 [A, B, C, ., D]
```

How would I get `C` to move into the empty space to the right of it? I know I would first have to look and see if there is an period next to a character. What I am having trouble with is the moving part. I want to move `C` and move the period in it's old spot.

Comment: There are no "empty spaces" in a list. Either every spaces it has is filled, or its empty. Now if you want to move `C` where `D` is, use `list.insert()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move an item inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3173154/1278112)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean, like, changing C and the dot position? You could have something like:

```
list_ = [A, B, C, ., D]
list_[2], list_[3] = list_[3], list_[2]
```

The list_ would look like [A, B, ., C, D].

Comment: No need for `temp` in python swaps, just use: `x[2], x[3] = x[3], x[2]`

Comment: Great catch! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You first have to find the position of the element you want to swap, and then you can swap it like this:

```
>>> l = ["A", "B", "C", ".", "D"]
>>> c_i = l.index("C")
>>> l[c_i], l[c_i+1] = l[c_i+1], l[c_i]
>>> l
['A', 'B', '.', 'C', 'D']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', '.', 'D']
old_index = my_list.index('.')
# Pop out the '.' and insert into the preceding index.
my_list.insert(old_index - 1, my_list.pop(old_index))
print(my_list)

> ['A', 'B', '.', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: Note the OP said: _"How would I get 'C' to move **into** the empty space to the right of it?"_. He was using the `.` as a place holder, and he wanted to move `C` into that space. Not move `C` past it.

Comment: OP also said: *I want to move 'C' and move the period in it's old spot.* It's a matter of perspective if you're moving 'C' or '.', really.