# reordering a list based on specific order

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to reorder a list with length n, where n can be any integer between 5 and 20.

example list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for each one of my generated lists, I want to move the last but one element [-2] to the start of the list [0] such that the final order becomes:

new_list = [5,1,2,3,4,6]

I have tried:

```
myorder =[1,2,3,4,5,6]


new_order = [(myorder[-2]), [i for i in myorder[:-2]], (myorder[-1])]
```

but this gives me a list in a list:

> [5, [1, 2, 3, 4], 6]

Is there a simple way to do this for list comprehension?

Comment: You can 1) flatten your own result back to a flat list, 2) do it the hard way and building a new list with [-2] at the beginning and the rest but [-1] to follow, or 3) use the `insert` method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173154/move-an-item-inside-a-list

Comment: `print([l[-2]] + l[:-2] + l[-1:])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
new_order = [myorder[-2]] + [i for i in myorder[:-2]] + [myorder[-1]]
```

Or, simplifying a bit,

```
new_order = [myorder[-2]] + myorder[:-2] + [myorder[-1]]
```

Comment: `myorder[:-2]` is the same as `[i for i in myorder[:-2]]`.

Comment: Yes, I know. I simply respected his syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list slicing.

**Ex:**

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print([l[-2]] + l[:-2] + l[-1:])
```

**Output:**

```
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> lst = [lst[-2]] + lst[:-2] + [lst[-1]]
>>> lst
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most general way of doing it:

```
example_list.insert(0, example_list.pop(-2))
```

You erase (pop) item -2 and insert it at position 0.