# algorithm reorder list of objects

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, sorting

I am searching for an algorithm to reorder an list of dictionarys or in javascript array of objects.
For example I have the following list of objects:

```
my_dict = [
    {
        "id": 123,
        "priority": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 234,
        "priority": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 345,
        "priority": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 654,
        "priority": 4
    }
]
```

Now I want to change the item with id 654 to be the first priority. So the other items gets automatically to priority 2,3 and 4.
This should be the result:

```
my_dict = [
    {
        "id": 654,
        "priority": 1
    }
    {
        "id": 123,
        "priority": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 234,
        "priority": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 345,
        "priority": 4
    },
]
```

Another example is when I want to decrease the priority of item 234 to priority 3 then the item with priority 3 should become priority 2 (from the original/first dict). There are should no priority be twice in this list and there should not be gaps.

```
my_dict = [
    {
        "id": 123,
        "priority": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 345,
        "priority": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 234,
        "priority": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 654,
        "priority": 4
    }
]
```

For clarification here is an other example.
If I move item with id 123 to priority 4 the item before should become priority 1,2 and 3.

```
my_dict = [

    {
        "id": 234,
        "priority": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 345,
        "priority": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 654,
        "priority": 3
    }
        {
        "id": 123,
        "priority": 4
    },
]
```

The list should always start with priority 1. Can somebody explain how I can implement it with python or javascript? I tried it with a for loop starting and 1 but this does not work.

Comment: You seem to represent information redundantly here.
The priority seems to be represented by both the position in the array as well as the `'priority'` member.
Don't do that. Either remove the priority member, or ignore the position in the array. Then increasing priority of an item should be simple.

Comment: theoretically you can ignore it. But practically I am getting it like this from database and then sort it by priority.

Comment: In that case your question is not fully defined. If you make `345` priority `3`, why should `234` become priority `2`? It seems there is a complex ruleset that you imply but don't define. Are the priorities integers? Can there only be one item of every priority? How exactly do other priorities change if items 'squeeze' in?

Comment: Why do you need the list to be sorted by priorities in the first place? Can't you just modify the priorities and then re-sort the list?

Comment: yes there can only one item with every priority. In this case the items 345 and 234 only swap the positions.

Comment: is must not be sorted by priority. I thought it was easier to find an algorithm to change the priority with a sorted list.

Comment: Are you looking for something other than just moving the item and then renumbering the effected items? (Heaps come to mind, but those are designed for specific access patterns).

Comment: @Mark no.  It should be possible to decrease or increase priority of an item

Comment: Are the priorities sequentially increasing? Could there be any gaps?

Comment: @Reti43 no gaps

Comment: Then I agree with previous comments that you should represent your data differently, i.e., `ids = [123, 234, 345, 654]` and a simple swap would do the trick. It would also be trivial to reconstruct the dicts as you have them here later on should you need them again.

Comment: After thinking about it I would keep the priority member and ditch the list instead, replacing it with something like a priority queue or heap. But it's hard to judge without more information about the exact usage scenario.

Comment: I have not so much items. Maybe 1000 or some more. What more informations do you need?

Comment: 1000 items can be a lot. If you have `n` items and you want to do `m` priority modifications on them, modifying them by sorting and re-enumerating would take `O(n*log(n)*m)` operations.

Comment: We would need a lot more information about what the exact usecase is. Like: what is the data? What is the required data format, both for the input and the output of your algorithm? How critical is timing? How many priority modifications will there be?

But all of that would make this question too big for stackoverflow. That's rather what https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is for.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the idea of having priority be represented by both the position in the list and the "priority" member. This is redundant and *will* cause trouble at some point.

Further, I have to make assumptions to answer this question, as the question is not complete.

Assumptions:

- In the end, the list should be sorted by priority again
- Priorities should end up being integers
- Priorities always start at 1 and enumerate the list without gaps

---

### First approach

Specify exactly where you want to put your item by using *halfs*. This is simple and everything else should fall in place.

### Example

Task: Move `234` to priority `3`.

Sadly, it is not uniquely defined what this is supposed to mean, as it is unclear where the old item of priority `3` should move to.

Instead move it to priority `3.5` to make it unambiguous, then re-sort and re-enumerate:

```
# Change priority of '234' to '3.5'
my_dict[1]["priority"] = 3.5

# Sort
my_dict.sort(key=lambda x: x["priority"])

# Re-enumerate
for (position, item) in enumerate(my_dict):
    item["priority"] = position + 1

print(my_dict)
```

```
[{'id': 123, 'priority': 1}, {'id': 345, 'priority': 2}, {'id': 234, 'priority': 3}, {'id': 654, 'priority': 4}]
```

---

For large datasets this is really slow though, as every single priority change is O(n*log(n)), as it requires a sort.

You should investigate in better data structures, like a heap or a linked list, depending on your exact usage scenario.

---

### Second approach

If we remove the `'priority'` member, we can write a much more efficient algorithm:

```
def move(data, original, target):
    data.insert(target, data.pop(original))

# Important: Start priorities at 0, not 1. This makes this a lot easier.

my_dict = [123, 234, 345, 654]
move(my_dict, 3, 0)
print(my_dict)

my_dict = [123, 234, 345, 654]
move(my_dict, 1, 2)
print(my_dict)
```

```
[654, 123, 234, 345]
[123, 345, 234, 654]
```

https://ideone.com/o9UcCb

For a longer discussion about how to move an item inside of a list, read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173154/move-an-item-inside-a-list).

Comment: it should move to priority 2. I will try it tomorrow and then give you a response but I think it should work. thank you

Comment: Yes, but not always. I think what you mean is it moves down if the replacing item has a lower priority, and moves up if the replacing item has a higher priority. But that's a guess, as you never state that anywhere in your original questions.

Comment: I updated the question. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Added a much faster version if you decide to ditch the `'priority'` member.

Comment: thank you I will try it out tomorrow because it is very late.

Comment: You're overcomplicating this. A simple swap in-place would suffice. You're creating a new list every time, even though the old one will probably be obsolete and of no interest after the swap. And if you must return a new copy, just copy the list and do the swap there instead of concatenating list slices.

Comment: Explain to me how a swap would solve this?
If you move priority item 3 to 0, it has to shift all values 0-2 up by one. This is not the case when using a simple swap. There is no way to achieve that efficiently without copying the entire list.

Comment: @Reti43 added a link to further information about how to move items inside of a list.

Comment: My swap terminology comes from a comment from the OP. I think he implied that something from priority 3 drops to 2, and the original 2 is pushed up to 3. If you do indeed have to implement a swap between non adjacent elements, then insert-pop would be the in-place approach.

Comment: I think @Reti43 is suggesting a simpler way to move items by mutating the  list in place like `my_list.insert(index_to, my_list.pop(index_from))`

Comment: This does not mutate the list in place. `my_list.pop()` does _not_ just remove one element, it shifts everything after the element to the left. `my_list.insert()` then shifts everything after it to the right. Which is about as fast as creating a new list. If you want to have faster insert/remove times, then you need to use something like a linked list. But then again it becomes very slow to search for the item you want to add/remove. As I said, a good compromise would be a red/black tree, which has O(log(n)) for both insert, remove and search. But that would make this a lot more complicated.

Comment: @Finomnis I think you should test that idea with some speed tests. In my tests with a list of 10k items. insert/pop = 6.03 µs, `move()` = 113 µs. As is often the case with Python, the simple solution is a good solution until proven wrong.

Comment: What I meant by in-place is mutate the original object (which both list.pop and list.insert do), instead of returning a new copy. *Regardless* of what shifts take place under the hood. It is also expresses intent in a clearer manner than what you did.

Comment: Benchmarks seem to agree with you. It's still not optimal either way, but `insert(pop())` seem to outsource the heavy lifting to some more efficient `memcpy()` or something.

Comment: @Mark Here some benchmarks, which tell that your suggested solution seems to be the one to go: https://ideone.com/zJQf5W

Comment: Gotta say the overhead of python is crazy. This would look completely different in a more performance oriented language.

Answer (score 0):

The discussions about a better data structure are spot-on.  But if you still want to implement what you asked for, we can write a straightforward JS version that does the naive thing:

```js
const changePriority = (xs, id, to,
  idx = xs .findIndex (({id: i}) => i == id),
  ys = [...xs .slice (0, idx), ...xs .slice (idx + 1)]
) => 
  [ ...ys . slice (0, to - 1), xs [idx], ...ys .slice(to - 1)]
    .map ((x, i) => ({...x, priority: i + 1}))

const dict = [{id: 123, priority: 1}, {id: 234, priority: 2}, {id: 345, priority: 3}, {id: 654, priority: 4}]

console .log (
  changePriority (dict, 654, 2)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that this depends upon your `id` and the new priorty, `to` actually existing in the input.  It wouldn't be hard to add error-checking.

Also note that this returns a new array, and doesn't mutate the original; we're not barbarians here.

Comment: Man, that's some write-only javascript code :D I'd most likely reject that if it was on my review table as 'not maintainable'

Comment: @Finomnis: This could be rewritten in an imperative fashion with some local temporary variables, but I've come to prefer an expression-only style, and I absolutely refuse to mutate input data.  I'm guessing that if it were more Pythonic, some people would prefer it, but I'd probably appreciate it less.  Is
[this version](http://link.sauyet.com/22) more to your liking?

Comment: Yes :D I gotta say I don't understand why you wouldn't change the input data. There's no reason to give yourself that restriction unless explicitely requested. Many algorithms work in-place, like python sort.

Comment: @Finomnis: I'm a big fan of functional programming, which is fairly easy to do in JS, and even easier with [a fairly popular library](https://ramdajs.com) I founded and maintain.  One of the key tenets of functional programming is to always work with immutable data.  *De gustibus non est disputandum*.