# How do you move an item in a list relative to its index?

Tags: python, list

I wanted to know if there was a way to move an object in a list based off of its original index.
For example here is an example list:

```
["Bill", "Bob", "John", "Rose", "Mike"]
```

And say I want to move Rose towards the beginning of the list by *n* amount of units.
So say *n* was 2 the list would look like:

```
["Bill", "Rose", "Bob", "John", "Mike"]
```

Comment: Use `index()`, `pop()` and `insert()` methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move an item inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173154/move-an-item-inside-a-list)

Comment: Use `index()` to gets the original position, `pop()` to remove it, and `insert()` to put it into the new position.

Answer (score 1):

```
l.insert(newindex, l.pop(oldindex))
```

should work, then in your example it will be

```
l = ["Bill", "Bob", "John", "Rose", "Mike"]
l.insert(1, l.pop(3))
```