# python How to Reorder elements in a list

Tags: python, list

Now I have a `list` like `["apple", "banana", "lemon", "strawberry", "orange"]`

If I want to reorder the `list`, for example:

Insert the strawberry into a new position, then the elements behind the strawberry need to move to the right one step. What should I do?

```
["apple", "strawberry", "banana", "lemon", "orange"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch position of two items in a Python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493920/how-to-switch-position-of-two-items-in-a-python-list)

Comment: or if you want to remove one item and insert it into other position, when you can use remove() and insert() functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move an item inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173154/move-an-item-inside-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `insert` and `pop` (in example I also use `index` for clarity).

```
x = ["apple", "banana", "lemon", "strawberry", "orange"]
x.insert(1, x.pop(x.index("strawberry")))
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
["apple", "strawberry", "banana", "lemon", "orange"]
```

`1` in the `insert` points to the index in list that you want your value to end up in.